# Does this equations represent the sphere?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, geometry

Consider complex numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$. Let $j=\sqrt{-1}$. Consider the set of points $$\mathcal{S}=(x_1x_2^*+x_1^*x_2,j(x_1x_2^*-x_1^*x_2,|x_1|^2-|x_2|^2)$$ for each point $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2=1$. Can this be the sphere?

Comment: just note that each component is a real one (just take complex conjugate and see it is the same as the component itself); hence, if you let

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
y_1 = x_1x_2^* + x_1^* x_2 \\
y_2 = j(x_1x_2^* -x_1^* x_2) \\
y_3 = |x_1|^2 - |x_2|^2
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

just compute $y_1^2 + y_2^2 + y_3^2$, and using the fact that $|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 = 1$, check this sum is $1$ too.

Comment: does it sum to 1?

Comment: Yes, just compute it. You have

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
y_1^2 = x_1^2 (x_2^*)^2 + (x_1^*)^2 x_2^2 + 2 |x_1|^2 |x_2|^2 \\
y_2^2 = - x_1^2 (x_2^*)^2 - (x_1^*)^2 x_2^2 + 2 |x_1|^2  |x_2|^2 \\
y_3^2 = |x_1|^4 + |x_2|^4 - 2 |x_1|^2 |x_2|^2
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

So

\begin{equation*}
y_1^2 + y_2^2 + y_3^2 = |x_1|^4 + |x_2|^4 + 2 |x_1|^2 |x_2|^2 = (|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2)^2 = 1
\end{equation*}